# Execute html code for a C# variable

Tags: c#, html, razor

Let me explain in detail
There is textarea in form.
On submitting form,the text of textarea get stored in database.
While display those texts from database I want to execute basic html code like <b><i><u>...etc
For example:-If user entered "<b>hello</b>" in textarea.Then this word "hello" will display in bold letters.

Comment: This is a very dangerous thing to do.  The user could also enter client-side scripting and your website would serve that scripting to its users as thought it came from you.

Comment: If you dump that text directly into a div, does that not work? EDIT: This is of course with the warning that @David has given above.

Comment: As @David mentioned, taking html tags can be dangerous. I would use [markdownsharp](https://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) instead

Comment: I want to allow only few html code not all

Comment: @Champ726337 like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/932418)?

Comment: No I want also to execute tags like <blink> <marquee>

Comment: @Champ726337: The internet at large does not want tags like `<blink>` or `<marquee>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw( [your HTML code from the database] )` in your View.

Comment: @Champ726337: It's pretty much all or nothing with HTML.  You could strip anything between <> characters that doesn't match those tags, if you want to dive into the magical lands of Regex.

Comment: Thank QQping I got my answer'if(str.Contains("<b>")){
 <text>   Html.Raw(str) </text>
  }
else{
   <text> str </text>
 }'

Answer (score 0):

In your Razor-file:

```
 <b>@myHtmlFromTheDatabase</b>
```

Comment: @Champ726337: In that case: clearify your question. Or at least: ask a question. I had the impression you that the textarea and database part were already done and you could not fix the last step...

Comment: I just take an example to explain what I want in last line